# Is it possible to use hibernate annotations to create an object resolving from multiple tables?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Is it possible to use hibernate annotations such as `@SecondaryTable` or `@JoinColumn` or something else to create a budgetFund object that contains these properties?

`int budgetFundsID`

`String semesterName`

`String fundCategoryName`

`BigDecimal fundAmount`

Here is an example of the tables that I am pulling from in the database:
[image]

Comment: what are the cardinalities? you can use `OneToMany`, `ManyToOne`, `OneToOne` and `ManyToMany`

Comment: @MappedSupperType can help

Comment: @XtremeBaumer I believe OneToOne as noted in the diagram

Comment: change the fields to `private Semester semester` and `private FundCategory fundCategory`. Then use `@OneToOne` to assign them as foreign keys. that would be the best way to do it in my opinion

Comment: @XtremeBaumer then when I do my query, if I have restrictions on the semesterID, would the field be `"semester.semesterID"`?

Comment: Yes, that is how you access fields of sub-classes (sub refers to classes which are contained in the entity class)

Comment: @XtremeBaumer ok, I will play with that and update my question with some of the code

Comment: Just a thought, in that situation I consider to create a view in the database and then map it directly to the @Column annotation

Comment: @XtremeBaumer How exactly do I use the foreign key annotation for OneToOne?  I know that in the budgetFund object I need `@OneToOne(mappedby="semesterID")
private Set<Semester> semester;`
but what do I do in the semester object code?

Comment: you do nothing there. only if you need a reference to the `budgetFund` class from the semester, then you need to add the same thing. also you don't use `Set`s for a `OneToOne` relation

Comment: @XtremeBaumer So I think I was wrong on the cardinality. There can be many budgetFund objects mapped to one semester object

Comment: then it is a `@OneToMany`, but still no `Set` (at least not in `budgetFund`).